# Chrome extension Manifest v3 not working with HTTPS localhost API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm currently migrating from Manifest v2 to Manifest v3 for a chrome extension. My extension uses public API served over HTTPS. I use a local instance of that API to test my extension which is served at `https://0.0.0.0:8080/`. However, for reasons I cannot understand, my extension fails to fetch anything from this URL. and the error displayed on the service worker's log is

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

If I switch my local API to be served at `http://0.0.0.0:8080/`, then the extension works fine. So basically, the extension works fine with all API URLs except for `https://0.0.0.0:8080/` on Manifest v3. I tried switching back to Manifest v2 and it worked so I'm not sure why it doesn't work on v3.

My manifest file looks like this

```
    {
  "name": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png"
    },
    "default_title": "..."
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "css": ["App.scss"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["storage"],
  "host_permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "*://*/*"],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["App.css"],
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try adding `https://0.0.0.0:8080/` to host_permissions and reload the extension. Maybe the port should be specified explicitly for https, which may be a bug in Chrome. FWIW, 0.0.0.0 is an invalid IP.

Comment: That didn't work. Adding host permissions have no effect on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem. It turns out that if you open the workers console and view the fetch request it says that the error is ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. Unfortunately I have no idea why the transition to Manifest V3 causes this (the local host is served via Flask with a self signed certificate which is not a problem in Manifest V2).

Edit: registered this as a bug at Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1395343